# Echo array with json_decode gives too many echoes

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, foursquare

I do get the strings I intend to. But I also get the first letter (or number) of the other data  in the json file.
 
E.g. I would like to have or should get the result:

> /Barrafina
>   Exceptional cooking here. Such simple but amazing dishes. Highly recommend the crab croquettes, lambs kidneys, skewers and the brain. Sherries are also superb here.
>   Matt Ta-Min/

**But instead I get**

> /Barrafina
>   ee
>   Exceptional cooking here. Such simple but amazing dishes. Highly recommend the crab croquettes, lambs kidneys, skewers and the brain. Sherries are also superb here.
>   5 5 E Eu uh h
>   Matt Ta-Min
>   /

What did I do wrong? here is the code:
  (If you have time and energy to look the JSON you will see from where eg. `5 5 E Eu uh h` comes.)
I appreciate any help.

```
        <?php
$client_id = 'CLIENT_ID';
$client_secret = 'SECRET';

$request_date = date('Ymd');

$base_url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/';
$endpoint = 'venues/explore?';
$params = 'near=London&limit=3&section=food&radius=1000';
$auth = "&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&v=$request_date";

$url = $base_url.$endpoint.$params.$auth;

$results = file_get_contents($url);

$json_results = json_decode($results,true);
//var_dump($json_results);

$items0 = $json_results['response']['groups']['0']['items']['0'];
$items1 = $json_results['response']['groups']['0']['items']['0']['tips'];
$items2 = $json_results['response']['groups']['0']['items']['0']['tips']['0'];
//<div style="align:center;">
foreach ( $items0+$items1 as $item){
  echo '<li>';
  echo $item['name'];
  echo $item['text'];
}
  foreach ( $items2 as $item){
  print $item['firstName']; print '&nbsp';  print $item['lastName'];
}
```

HERE is the json decoded:

```
array(2) { ["meta"]=> array(2) { ["code"]=> int(200) ["requestId"]=> string(24) "55fb1f91498e70ad2e246eed" } ["response"]=> array(10) { ["suggestedFilters"]=> array(2) { ["header"]=> string(12) "Tap to show:" ["filters"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(13) "With specials" ["key"]=> string(8) "specials" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(8) "Open now" ["key"]=> string(7) "openNow" } } } ["geocode"]=> array(8) { ["what"]=> string(0) "" ["where"]=> string(6) "london" ["center"]=> array(2) { ["lat"]=> float(51.50853) ["lng"]=> float(-0.12574) } ["displayString"]=> string(38) "London, Greater London, United Kingdom" ["cc"]=> string(2) "GB" ["geometry"]=> array(1) { ["bounds"]=> array(2) { ["ne"]=> array(2) { ["lat"]=> float(51.691643999656) ["lng"]=> float(0.33418999705203) } ["sw"]=> array(2) { ["lat"]=> float(51.284674044171) ["lng"]=> float(-0.50855792793694) } } } ["slug"]=> string(6) "london" ["longId"]=> string(17) "72057594040571679" } ["warning"]=> array(1) { ["text"]=> string(114) "There aren't a lot of results near you. Try something more general, reset your filters, or expand the search area." } ["headerLocation"]=> string(6) "London" ["headerFullLocation"]=> string(6) "London" ["headerLocationGranularity"]=> string(4) "city" ["query"]=> string(4) "food" ["totalResults"]=> int(246) ["suggestedBounds"]=> array(2) { ["ne"]=> array(2) { ["lat"]=> float(51.510800358799) ["lng"]=> float(-0.12174369837641) } ["sw"]=> array(2) { ["lat"]=> float(51.508100699014) ["lng"]=> float(-0.13015278468604) } } ["groups"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["type"]=> string(18) "Recommended Places" ["name"]=> string(11) "recommended" ["items"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["reasons"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(0) ["items"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["summary"]=> string(20) "This spot is popular" ["type"]=> string(7) "general" ["reasonName"]=> string(23) "globalInteractionReason" } } } ["venue"]=> array(17) { ["id"]=> string(24) "53bab96d498e7e355fb53d6c" ["name"]=> string(9) "Barrafina" ["contact"]=> array(6) { ["phone"]=> string(13) "+442074401456" ["formattedPhone"]=> string(16) "+44 20 7440 1456" ["twitter"]=> string(13) "barrafinaadst" ["facebook"]=> string(15) "705351912878392" ["facebookUsername"]=> string(23) "BarrafinaAdelaideStreet" ["facebookName"]=> string(25) "Barrafina Adelaide Street" } ["location"]=> array(10) { ["address"]=> string(14) "10 Adelaide St" ["crossStreet"]=> string(13) "William IV St" ["lat"]=> float(51.509450528906) ["lng"]=> float(-0.12594824153122) ["postalCode"]=> string(8) "WC2N 4HZ" ["cc"]=> string(2) "GB" ["city"]=> string(6) "London" ["state"]=> string(14) "Greater London" ["country"]=> string(14) "United Kingdom" ["formattedAddress"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(30) "10 Adelaide St (William IV St)" [1]=> string(6) "London" [2]=> string(14) "Greater London" [3]=> string(8) "WC2N 4HZ" [4]=> string(14) "United Kingdom" } } ["categories"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(24) "4bf58dd8d48988d150941735" ["name"]=> string(18) "Spanish Restaurant" ["pluralName"]=> string(19) "Spanish Restaurants" ["shortName"]=> string(7) "Spanish" ["icon"]=> array(2) { ["prefix"]=> string(52) "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/spanish_" ["suffix"]=> string(4) ".png" } ["primary"]=> bool(true) } } ["verified"]=> bool(false) ["stats"]=> array(3) { ["checkinsCount"]=> int(357) ["usersCount"]=> int(278) ["tipCount"]=> int(26) } ["url"]=> string(22) "http://barrafina.co.uk" ["price"]=> array(3) { ["tier"]=> int(2) ["message"]=> string(8) "Moderate" ["currency"]=> string(2) "Â£" } ["rating"]=> float(9) ["ratingColor"]=> string(6) "00B551" ["ratingSignals"]=> int(80) ["allowMenuUrlEdit"]=> bool(true) ["hours"]=> array(2) { ["status"]=> string(19) "Open until 11:00 PM" ["isOpen"]=> bool(true) } ["specials"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(0) ["items"]=> array(0) { } } ["photos"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(31) ["groups"]=> array(0) { } } ["hereNow"]=> array(3) { ["count"]=> int(0) ["summary"]=> string(11) "Nobody here" ["groups"]=> array(0) { } } } ["tips"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> string(24) "55db9142498ede18f5b31b81" ["createdAt"]=> int(1440452930) ["text"]=> string(164) "Exceptional cooking here. Such simple but amazing dishes. Highly recommend the crab croquettes, lambs kidneys, skewers and the brain. Sherries are also superb here." ["type"]=> string(4) "user" ["canonicalUrl"]=> string(52) "https://foursquare.com/item/55db9142498ede18f5b31b81" ["likes"]=> array(3) { ["count"]=> int(2) ["groups"]=> array(0) { } ["summary"]=> string(7) "2 likes" } ["logView"]=> bool(true) ["todo"]=> array(1) { ["count"]=> int(0) } ["user"]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(8) "98683884" ["firstName"]=> string(4) "Matt" ["lastName"]=> string(6) "Ta-Min" ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" ["photo"]=> array(2) { ["prefix"]=> string(31) "https://irs1.4sqi.net/img/user/" ["suffix"]=> string(30) "/98683884-1MJ0OTISTPZWSBRJ.jpg" } } } } ["referralId"]=> string(30) "e-3-53bab96d498e7e355fb53d6c-0" } } } } } }
```

Here is JSON

```
{"meta":{"code":200,"requestId":"55fbde58498e7fdbd12f8fb2"},"response":{"suggestedFilters":{"header":"Tap to show:","filters":[{"name":"With specials","key":"specials"},{"name":"Open now","key":"openNow"}]},"geocode":{"what":"","where":"london","center":{"lat":51.50853,"lng":-0.12574},"displayString":"London, Greater London, United Kingdom","cc":"GB","geometry":{"bounds":{"ne":{"lat":51.691643999655895,"lng":0.33418999705203406},"sw":{"lat":51.28467404417054,"lng":-0.5085579279369435}}},"slug":"london","longId":"72057594040571679"},"warning":{"text":"There aren't a lot of results near you. Try something more general, reset your filters, or expand the search area."},"headerLocation":"London","headerFullLocation":"London","headerLocationGranularity":"city","query":"food","totalResults":246,"suggestedBounds":{"ne":{"lat":51.5108003587992,"lng":-0.12174369837640672},"sw":{"lat":51.50810069901375,"lng":-0.1301527846860385}},"groups":[{"type":"Recommended Places","name":"recommended","items":[{"reasons":{"count":0,"items":[{"summary":"This spot is popular","type":"general","reasonName":"globalInteractionReason"}]},"venue":{"id":"53bab96d498e7e355fb53d6c","name":"Barrafina","contact":{"phone":"+442074401456","formattedPhone":"+44 20 7440 1456","twitter":"barrafinaadst","facebook":"705351912878392","facebookUsername":"BarrafinaAdelaideStreet","facebookName":"Barrafina Adelaide Street"},"location":{"address":"10 Adelaide St","crossStreet":"William IV St","lat":51.50945052890648,"lng":-0.1259482415312226,"postalCode":"WC2N 4HZ","cc":"GB","city":"London","state":"Greater London","country":"United Kingdom","formattedAddress":["10 Adelaide St (William IV St)","London","Greater London","WC2N 4HZ","United Kingdom"]},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d150941735","name":"Spanish Restaurant","pluralName":"Spanish Restaurants","shortName":"Spanish","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/spanish_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":357,"usersCount":278,"tipCount":26},"url":"http:\/\/barrafina.co.uk","rating":9.0,"ratingColor":"00B551","ratingSignals":80,"allowMenuUrlEdit":true,"hours":{"status":"Closed until Noon","isOpen":false},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"photos":{"count":31,"groups":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"summary":"Nobody here","groups":[]}},"tips":[{"id":"55db9142498ede18f5b31b81","createdAt":1440452930,"text":"Exceptional cooking here. Such simple but amazing dishes. Highly recommend the crab croquettes, lambs kidneys, skewers and the brain. Sherries are also superb here.","type":"user","canonicalUrl":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/item\/55db9142498ede18f5b31b81","likes":{"count":2,"groups":[],"summary":"2 likes"},"logView":true,"todo":{"count":0},"user":{"id":"98683884","firstName":"Matt","lastName":"Ta-Min","gender":"male","photo":{"prefix":"https:\/\/irs1.4sqi.net\/img\/user\/","suffix":"\/98683884-1MJ0OTISTPZWSBRJ.jpg"}}}],"referralId":"e-3-53bab96d498e7e355fb53d6c-0"}]}]}}
```

Comment: I would like to see the JSON since I got time and energy, but unfortunately I've got no JSON to see :( => `{"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"invalid_auth","errorDetail":"Missing access credentials. See https:\/\/developer.foursquare.com\/docs\/oauth.html for details."},"response":{}}`

Comment: Need to see the JSON you are trying to use

Comment: Actually, it would be more useful if you could edit your question with the result of `var_dump($json_results); exit();` uncommented right at line 17

Comment: edited and added the JSON

Comment: @Mik_A: Could there be a problem with your array merge ($items0+$items1) ? .. Remember that, if array keys exist in both arrays, the element from the first array will be used and the matching key's element from the second array will be ignored. You could try to var_dump the merged arrays first to see if you can spot something unexpected.

Comment: I tried with the separetly. It doesent help.
If I only echo the first one (Name) the everything fine. 
But if i echo something more, the the first one gets a letter after it :S

But if I echo the last one (deeper in JSON) I get extra. and if i echo the two string. I get extra letters doubled.